# Laravel 5: show me the post title that this comment belongs to on user profile

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to display the post title that user comment belongs to on his profile page.

This is what I'm doing on the user's profile

```
public function show($user, Post $post)
{
    $user = User::whereName($user)->with('posts.votes')->with('comments')->firstOrFail();
    $comments = $user->comments;
    $linkKarma = User::find($user->id)->votes()->sum('value');
    $commentKarma = User::find($user->id)->commentvotes()->sum('value');
    $total_comments = $user->comments->count();

    $isModerator = false;

    return view('user/profile')->with('user', $user)
                                ->with('linkKarma', $linkKarma)
                                ->with('commentKarma', $commentKarma)
                                ->with('comments', $comments)
                                ->with('total_comments', $total_comments)
                                ->with('isModerator', $isModerator);
}
```

I am basically getting everything he has, from `posts`, `votes` and `comments` - However, I am not able to show the post that these comments belong to on the user profile page.

I can use `$comment->post_id` within a `foreach()` but that will only get me the post ID but I can't use `$comment->post->title` it will error `Trying to get a property of a none object`

How can I do that?

My Database

```
posts: id, title, user_id, subreddit_id...
comments: id, comment, user_id, post_id...
user: id, name, email...
```

`Post` Model

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function subreddit() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Subreddit');
}

public function votes() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Vote');
}

public function moderators() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Moderator');
}

public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

`Comment` Model

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function commentvotes() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\CommentVote');
}

public function subreddit() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Subreddit');
}
```

`User` Model

```
public function subreddit() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Subreddit');
}

public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}

public function votes() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Vote','App\Post');
}

public function commentvotes() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\CommentVote','App\Comment');
}

public function moderators() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Moderator');
}

public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$comment->posts->title
```

(notice it is "posts" not "post")

Your Comment model has the function `posts` so when you access it from the comment, you access it with that function name, as shown above.

I would rename posts to post, as a comment belongs to ONE post, not multiple posts.

Also change

```
$user = User::whereName($user)->with('posts.votes')->with('comments')->firstOrFail();
```

to be

```
$user = User::whereName($user)->with('posts.votes', 'comments.posts')->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: This gives `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Can you please verify that the function name inside the Comment model is `posts`, and that inside the view file, in a foreach loop, you are accessing it via `$comment->posts->title` ? Also what is output when you dd or print_r `$comment` ?

Comment: I cannot access `$comment->posts->title` that's the problem. Comments are not chained with posts because I am already eager loading `posts.votes` - `dd($comments)` will get a collection of all the user's comments.

Comment: Try changing `$user = User::whereName($user)->with('posts.votes')->with('comments')->firstOrFail();` to be `$user = User::whereName($user)->with('posts.votes')->with('comments.posts')->firstOrFail();`

Comment: I tried that but the `posts` collection inside the comments is always null.

Comment: Try changing that line to be: `$user = User::whereName($user)->with('posts.votes', 'comments.posts')->firstOrFail();`

Comment: posts collection inside comments is still null

Comment: Please provide the code you are using to access the users comments posts title. Also verify you actually have a post with the id that matches the post_id in the comment record. Make sure your function names match up because your question shows posts but accessing via post.

Comment: well you were right, chaining posts to comments will work, but I had to fix my model relations first by adding the foreign key `post_id` to Comment model on `posts()`. It is now working